# Proper Code Commenting Etiquette?

Tags: java, comments

So commenting functions in code seems to be a common staple amongst the languages, however, what is the *proper* way to comment on code? I have some example code, riddled with static abuse and poorly designed mechanics (still new to Java), with some comments. Note: This is for a Black Jack project I turned in so it was a school project originally.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main extends Application {

    //Screen dimensions
    private static int width;
    private static int height;
    private static int value;

    //Make new card regions
    private static Region userZERO;
    private static Region userONE;
    private static Region userTWO;
    private static Region userTHREE;
    private static Region userFOUR;
    private static Region dealerZERO;
    private static Region dealerONE;
    private static Region dealerTWO;
    private static Region dealerTHREE;
    private static Region dealerFOUR;

    //Scene components
    private static Button hitButton;
    private static Button endButton;
    private static Button resetButton;
    private static VBox root;
    private static HBox userCardHolder;
    private static HBox buttonContainer;
    private static HBox dealerCardHolder;
    private static Label text;
    private static Scene scene;

    //Card values
    private static ArrayList<Card> user = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Card> dealer = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

    private static boolean dealerBusted = false;

    //Miscellaneous variable assignments

    /* Constant random variables using
     * ThreadLocalRandom, speeds up to x3
     * faster than Java.util.Random, and is
     * unique to this thread.
     */

    private static final ThreadLocalRandom RANDOM = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    /* Main is first method called upon
     * start, which uses the singular
     * method, launch, to use the Start
     * method which passes a Stage reference
     * to begin building the Window.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        width = ((int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth());
        height = ((int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight());
        cards = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Card.values()));

        /* Creates rectangular regions for each card
         * that will be represented in the GUI. Size
         * is dictated by screen width and height,
         * and in the shape of a rectangle to adapt
         * to the shape of a playing card. Will set
         * the preferential size, however has
         * possibility of error if application is
         * minimized.
         */

        userZERO    = new Region(); userZERO.setPrefSize(width / 12, height / 4.5);
        userONE     = new Region(); userONE.setPrefSize(width / 12, height / 4.5);
        userTWO     = new Region(); userTWO.setPrefSize(width / 12, height / 4.5);
        userTHREE   = new Region(); userTHREE.setPrefSize(width / 12, height / 4.5);
        userFOUR    = new Region(); userFOUR.setPrefSize(width / 12, height / 4.5);
        dealerZERO  = new Region(); dealerZERO.setPrefSize(width / 12, height / 4.5);
        dealerONE   = new Region(); dealerONE.setPrefSize(width / 12, height / 4.5);
        dealerTWO   = new Region(); dealerTWO.setPrefSize(width / 12, height / 4.5);
        dealerTHREE = new Region(); dealerTHREE.setPrefSize(width / 12, height / 4.5);
        dealerFOUR  = new Region(); dealerFOUR.setPrefSize(width / 12, height / 4.5);

        /* Sets the .css limitations of the regions.
         * First, sets up image as the BACK.png image
         * in the resources folder. Then edits
         * background size to auto cover the entire
         * region to prevent inappropriately sized
         * images per region.
         */

        userZERO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        userONE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        userTWO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        userTHREE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        userFOUR.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        dealerZERO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        dealerONE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        dealerTWO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        dealerTHREE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        dealerFOUR.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");


        /* Setting up scene / Window information,
         * and root information. Adding sub-roots
         * to main-root for customized grid-pattern
         * to contain cards on two rows, and a row
         * of buttons in the middle independent
         * of the card rows.
         */

        root = new VBox(height / 25);
        root.setPrefSize(width, height);
        root.setMaxSize(width, height);
        root.setMinSize(width, height);
        root.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACKGROUND.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");

        text = new Label();
        text.setPrefSize(width / 2, height / 20);
        text.setStyle(" -fx-text-alignment: center; -fx-font: 48 arial;");
        text.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.CENTER);
        text.setTextFill(Color.RED.darker());

        hitButton = new Button("HIT");
        endButton = new Button("END");
        resetButton = new Button("RESET");

        userCardHolder = new HBox(width / 12);
        userCardHolder.getChildren().addAll(userZERO, userONE, userTWO, userTHREE, userFOUR);
        userCardHolder.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.CENTER);

        buttonContainer = new HBox(width / 10);
        buttonContainer.getChildren().addAll(hitButton, resetButton, endButton);
        buttonContainer.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.CENTER);

        dealerCardHolder = new HBox(width / 20);
        dealerCardHolder.getChildren().addAll(dealerZERO, dealerONE, dealerTWO, dealerTHREE, dealerFOUR);
        dealerCardHolder.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.CENTER);

        root.getChildren().add(userCardHolder);
        root.getChildren().add(text);
        root.getChildren().add(buttonContainer);
        root.getChildren().add(dealerCardHolder);

        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        hitButton.setPrefSize(width / 4.5, height / 12);
        endButton.setPrefSize(width / 4.5, height / 12);
        resetButton.setPrefSize(width / 4.5, height / 12);

        user.clear();
        dealer.clear();
        buttonHandlers();
        begin();
    }

    public static void buttonHandlers() {
        /* Stop!
         * Lambda Time!
         */
        hitButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (user.size() < 5) {
                Card card = cards.get(RANDOM.nextInt(cards.size()));
                user.add(card);
                cards.remove(card);
                switch (user.size()) {
                    case 3:
                        userTWO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/" + user.get(user.size() - 1).toString() + ".png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        userTHREE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/" + user.get(user.size() - 1).toString() + ".png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        userFOUR.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/" + user.get(user.size() - 1).toString() + ".png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        endButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            for (Card c : dealer) {
                switch (dealer.indexOf(c)) {
                    case 0:
                        dealerZERO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/" + c.toString() + ".png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        dealerONE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/" + c.toString() + ".png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        dealerTWO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/" + c.toString() + ".png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        dealerTHREE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/" + c.toString() + ".png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        dealerFOUR.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/" + c.toString() + ".png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
                        break;
                }
            }

            /* Checking scenarios for valid ending:
             *
             * Checks if one or both entites busted, and decided winner based
             * on card amount and card value. House wins by default if same
             * card values and card amount.
             */
            if (checkForBust(user) && checkForBust(dealer)) {
                System.out.println("BOTH BUSTED!");
                text.setText("BOTH BUSTED!");
            }
            else if (checkForBust(user) && !checkForBust(dealer)) {
                System.out.println("YOU BUSTED!");
                text.setText("DEALER WON!");
            }
            else if (!checkForBust(user) && checkForBust(dealer)) {
                System.out.println("DEALER BUSTED!");
                text.setText("YOU WON!");
            }
            else if (getValue(user) > getValue(dealer)) {
                System.out.println("USER WINS");
                text.setText("YOU WON!");
            }
            else if ((getValue(user) == getValue(dealer)) && (user.size() >= dealer.size())) {
                System.out.println("DEALER WINS");
                text.setText("DEALER WON!");
            }
            else if ((getValue(user) == getValue(dealer)) && (user.size() <= dealer.size())) {
                System.out.println("USER WINS");
                text.setText("USER WON!");
            }
            else if ((getValue(user) == getValue(dealer)) && (user.size() == dealer.size())) {
                System.out.println("DEALER WINS");
                text.setText("DEALER WON!");
            }
            else if (getValue(dealer) > getValue(user)) {
                System.out.println("DEALER WINS");
                text.setText("DEALER WON!");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
                text.setText("ERROR GETTING WINNER!");
            }
        });

        resetButton.setOnAction(e ->{
            begin();
        });
    }

    public static boolean checkForBust(List<Card> lc) {

        value = 0;

        for (Card c : lc) {
            value += c.getValue();
        }

        if (lc.contains(Card.ACE_OF_CLUBS) && value > 21) { value -= 10; }
        if (lc.contains(Card.ACE_OF_DIAMONDS) && value > 21) { value -= 10; }
        if (lc.contains(Card.ACE_OF_HEARTS) && value > 21) { value -= 10; }
        if (lc.contains(Card.ACE_OF_SPADES) && value > 21) { value -= 10; }

        return value > 21;
    }

    public static int getValue(List<Card> lc) {

        value = 0;

        for (Card c : lc) {
            value += c.getValue();
        }

        if (lc.contains(Card.ACE_OF_CLUBS) && value > 21) { value -= 10; }
        if (lc.contains(Card.ACE_OF_DIAMONDS) && value > 21) { value -= 10; }
        if (lc.contains(Card.ACE_OF_HEARTS) && value > 21) { value -= 10; }
        if (lc.contains(Card.ACE_OF_SPADES) && value > 21) { value -= 10; }

        return value;
    }

    public static void begin() {

        text.setText("");

        cards.clear();
        user.clear();
        dealer.clear();
        cards = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Card.values()));

        userZERO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        userONE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        userTWO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        userTHREE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        userFOUR.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        dealerZERO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        dealerONE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        dealerTWO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        dealerTHREE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        dealerFOUR.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/BACK.png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");

        Card card = cards.get(RANDOM.nextInt(cards.size()));
        user.add(card);
        cards.remove(card);
        card = cards.get(RANDOM.nextInt(cards.size()));
        user.add(card);
        cards.remove(card);
        userZERO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/" + user.get(0) + ".png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        userONE.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/" + user.get(1) + ".png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");
        card = cards.get(RANDOM.nextInt(cards.size()));
        dealer.add(card);
        cards.remove(card);
        card = cards.get(RANDOM.nextInt(cards.size()));
        dealer.add(card);
        cards.remove(card);
        dealerZERO.setStyle(" -fx-background-image: url(\"images/" + dealer.get(0) + ".png\"); -fx-background-size: cover, auto;");

        while(getValue(dealer) < 16 && dealer.size() < 5) {
            card = cards.get(RANDOM.nextInt(cards.size()));
            dealer.add(card);
            cards.remove(card);
        }
    }


    /* Switch to enum values:
     * Card values and suits. Nested enum classes in a main class.
     */

    public enum Card {

        ACE_OF_SPADES(11, Suit.SPADES),
        ACE_OF_HEARTS(11, Suit.HEARTS),
        ACE_OF_DIAMONDS(11, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        ACE_OF_CLUBS(11, Suit.CLUBS),

        TWO_OF_SPADES(2, Suit.SPADES),
        TWO_OF_HEARTS(2, Suit.HEARTS),
        TWO_OF_DIAMONDS(2, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        TWO_OF_CLUBS(2, Suit.CLUBS),

        THREE_OF_SPADES(3, Suit.SPADES),
        THREE_OF_HEARTS(3, Suit.HEARTS),
        THREE_OF_DIAMONDS(3, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        THREE_OF_CLUBS(3, Suit.CLUBS),

        FOUR_OF_SPADES(4, Suit.SPADES),
        FOUR_OF_HEARTS(4, Suit.HEARTS),
        FOUR_OF_DIAMONDS(4, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        FOUR_OF_CLUBS(4, Suit.CLUBS),

        FIVE_OF_SPADES(5, Suit.SPADES),
        FIVE_OF_HEARTS(5, Suit.HEARTS),
        FIVE_OF_DIAMONDS(5, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        FIVE_OF_CLUBS(5, Suit.CLUBS),

        SIX_OF_SPADES(6, Suit.SPADES),
        SIX_OF_HEARTS(6, Suit.HEARTS),
        SIX_OF_DIAMONDS(6, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        SIX_OF_CLUBS(6, Suit.CLUBS),

        SEVEN_OF_SPADES(7, Suit.SPADES),
        SEVEN_OF_HEARTS(7, Suit.HEARTS),
        SEVEN_OF_DIAMONDS(7, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        SEVEN_OF_CLUBS(7, Suit.CLUBS),

        EIGHT_OF_SPADES(8, Suit.SPADES),
        EIGHT_OF_HEARTS(8, Suit.HEARTS),
        EIGHT_OF_DIAMONDS(8, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        EIGHT_OF_CLUBS(8, Suit.CLUBS),

        NINE_OF_SPADES(9, Suit.SPADES),
        NINE_OF_HEARTS(9, Suit.HEARTS),
        NINE_OF_DIAMONDS(9, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        NINE_OF_CLUBS(9, Suit.CLUBS),

        TEN_OF_SPADES(10, Suit.SPADES),
        TEN_OF_HEARTS(10, Suit.HEARTS),
        TEN_OF_DIAMONDS(10, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        TEN_OF_CLUBS(10, Suit.CLUBS),

        JACK_OF_SPADES(10, Suit.SPADES),
        JACK_OF_HEARTS(10, Suit.HEARTS),
        JACK_OF_DIAMONDS(10, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        JACK_OF_CLUBS(10, Suit.CLUBS),

        QUEEN_OF_SPADES(10, Suit.SPADES),
        QUEEN_OF_HEARTS(10, Suit.HEARTS),
        QUEEN_OF_DIAMONDS(10, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        QUEEN_OF_CLUBS(10, Suit.CLUBS),

        KING_OF_SPADES(10, Suit.SPADES),
        KING_OF_HEARTS(10, Suit.HEARTS),
        KING_OF_DIAMONDS(10, Suit.DIAMONDS),
        KING_OF_CLUBS(10, Suit.CLUBS);

        private int value;
        private Suit suit;

        Card(int value, Suit suit) {
            this.value = value;
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        public int getValue() { return value; }
    }

    public enum Suit {
        HEARTS(),
        DIAMONDS(),
        CLUBS(),
        SPADES();
        Suit(){}
    }
}
```

When submitting code to be observed, should I not have comments, should I have comments, should I utilize the JavaDocs feature, etc. Then there is how should I comment, if I do 2 or 3 lines, should I use the multiple method?

```
/* store some comments
 * around here
 */
```

or simply `//comment here` a few times

Moving back to the JavaDocs, would that be ideal for a school project, does it make it seem 'professional' in a sense? Is having the code written in Java and English make it professional or is that hurting the professionalism. There is also, should I describe WHAT they are? What they DO, both, etc? I obviously don't want 99% of my code to be comments, but I do want some comments, without a filler-type content you'd see in books. What factor allows information to be ideally and widely accepted to be written down in comments?

Comment: Did you read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html?

Comment: Not relevant to your question but I would comment that your methods are doing too much.  They should just do **one** *thing* and should fit on your screen.  `start` is doing too many things, consider to split into multiple methods

Comment: It really depends on the organization, if you can get into the habit of using java doc style commenting I would do it.  Take a look at the coding standards from highly regarded companies like Google.

Comment: @Scary Wombat  Overall some of the terminology was a bit too confusing for me within that, I haven't gotten to the point where I could read that with ease, but I can still understand a portion of it. However I am not advanced enough in this area, in both English (apparently), and the coding terms.

Comment: Javadocs are great, it allows other developers to know what your methods and fields are doing. I would write how a method works/behaves at the "black-box" level in the Javadoc, and if I used anything complicated in the actual implementation, I would add in comments appropriately.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to comment on what the code is doing and potentially why, the how is usually not necessary for well formed code.

Comment: Also do not forget about the power of self-documenting code.  You code fails in some respects, like when you use some generic method name like `begin` **but** the method is doing a lot more than `beginning`

Answer (score 1):

There are several different schools of thoughts about comments. Some developers think of comments as *apologies* for poorly written code, but I disagree with this notion and find them useful. A substitute to reading articles is to analyze the source code of popular open source projects written in Java and try and emulate their style. The popular Java IDEs such as NetBeans, Eclipse, and IntelliJ are open source projects written in Java so they're good places to start.

- Netbeans: https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans
- Eclipse: https://github.com/eclipse
- IntelliJ: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community

You don't have to understand the logic, just take notes on how the authors comment their code. After a while you should start to see some similarities which is great, go ahead and assimilate them into your coding repertoire.

Answer (score 0):

When we are forced to use comments it is a strong smell that something is wrong. Except in javadocs, when we really need to comment a code, probably it is not so well writen or even doesn't represent properly the business rules.

For example: you have the comment "//Screen dimensions" there. Why not create and object with those properties?

I love [Refactor.Guru](https://refactoring.guru/smells/comments) because it explains a lot of bad smells, code patterns, refactoring strategies and so on. Also, it has some tips about when and how comment.

Comment: First time I have ever seen that site, very accurate and useful content. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: you are welcome. In general they offers a course also which is basic, but very good.